# How to parse and get data from little complicated json in swift4?

Tags: json, parsing, codable, decodable, swift4.2

I need help with parsing json file called weather.json.
weather.json

```
{
  "weatherinfo": {
        "local": [
          {
            "country": "Korea",
            "weather": "rainy",
            "temperature": "20"
          },
          {
            "country": "US",
            "weather": "sunny",
            "temperature": "30"
          }
        ]
  }
}
```

And here's my code

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
    var weatherInfo: WeatherInfo?
}

struct WeatherInfo: Decodable {
    let local: [Local]?
}

struct Local: Decodable {
    let country: String?
    let weather: String?
    let temperature: String?
}
```

inside `func viewDidLoad() in UIViewController`

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
guard let path: String = Bundle.main.path( forResource: "weather", ofType: "json") else { return }
let jsonURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonURL) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print("pass1")
    do {
        let weather = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: data)
        print("parsing pass..")
        print(weather)  // Weather(weatherInfo: nil)
        print(weather.weatherInfo?.local?[0].country)  // nil
    } catch let jsonErr{
        print("Error: \(jsonErr)")
    }
}.resume()
```

I succeed parsing but I can't get data from weather constant..
How can I get country value from that json file..?
Can anyone fix my code please?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `URLSession` for reading a file in the bundle is overkill. Just get the `Data`.

Second of all declare everything non-optional since you clearly know that all keys are available

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
    let weatherinfo: WeatherInfo // note the lowercase spelling
}

struct WeatherInfo: Decodable {
    let local: [Local]
}

struct Local: Decodable {
    let country: String
    let weather: String
    let temperature: String
}
```

The countries are in the array `local` in `weatherInfo`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "weather", withExtension: "json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
for location in result.weatherinfo.local {
    print("In \(location.country) the weather is \(location.weather) and the temperature is \(location.temperature) degrees")
}
```